# Closest divisor

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Given two whole numbers, $N$ and $m$, a third whole number $c$ is the one that holds $N\bmod c= 0$ and has the minimal $|c-m|$.

In other words, $c$ is a divisor of $N$ closest to $m$.

Examples (in the form of $f(N, m) = c$):

$f(10, 2) = 2$

$f(13, 10) = 13$

$f(25, 7) = 5$

$f(60, 10) = 10$

I'm trying to figure out an efficient algorithm to find $c$, but I can't find a similar problem to relate to it. I'm not sure if I'm not using the right keywords.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: what algorithm are you currently using?

Comment: I branch upwards and downwards from m. i.e. checking one-by one m+1, m-1, m+2, m-2 etc...

Comment: $f(13,10)=13$, not $1$.  Also, $f(60,10)=10$, since $10$ divides $60$.

Comment: I edited it, but is it really elementary? I'm looking for an *efficient* algorithm, not just a simple search.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewConroy.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "efficient" here.  How efficient is your current method? How does it compare to the efficiency of simply finding all divisors and checking them for closeness to $m$?  Why do you need an "efficient" method of doing this? Tell us more! Cheers!

Comment: I would like to do it as fast as possible. My current method performs poorly if I get, for example, a large prime number N and m~N/2. In this case my method will perform ~N divisions. I would like to avoid such cases, if it's at all possible. Finding all divisors will also perform poorly in such a case.

Comment: @scf Finding the closest divisor must be at least as hard as factoring : If we can determine the closest divisor somehow and we choose the second number as the rounded square root of the first, we will get a non-trivial factor (unless the given number happens to be a prime). Only if the number of divisors gets astronomically high verifying the possible divisors might be more difficult. So, first of all, you should clarify whether we know the factorization.

Comment: No, I do not know N's factorization.

Comment: Then there won't be an efficient method because this would give us an efficient method for integer factorizaion and currently we do not know such a method.

Comment: Okay, thank you. If you'd like to phrase this statement as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we could find out the closest divisor efficiently, choosing the second number as the rounded square root of the given number would either give us a non-trivial factor or it would show that the given number is prime which makes the problem trivial.

Hence, finding the closest divisor must at least be as hard as integer factoring. But we do not know an efficient method for integer factoring, so there will not be an efficient method to find the closest divisor either.