# Minimising $x+y$ in $x^y=a$

Tags: number-theory, optimization, prime-factorization

Regarding [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4838012/finding-the-smallest-set-of-values-that-make-an-exponent-of-a-known-value), the question asks for minimizing $x+y$, given $x^y=a$, (for a constant real positive $a$) for real and positive values of $x$ and $y$.
Now $(x,y)=\left(\exp\left({2W\left(\frac{\sqrt{\ln a}}{2}\right)}\right),\frac{\ln(a)}{2W\left(\frac{\sqrt{\ln a}}{2}\right)}\right)$ was the solution in that case. But I am curious to know what would happen if we restrict $x$ and $y$ to being positive integers (with $a$ being an integer greater than $1$) and then try to minimise $x+y$ under the given constraint.

I think that using the prime factorization of $a$, something like $\alpha^A\beta^B\gamma^C...$ (where $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are primes), we might be able to come to a solution, but so far, I haven't been able to proceed. Perhaps something with the common divisors of the exponents in the prime factorization? (That might denote possible values of $y$)

I will link this question to the previous one too.

All help and clarification requests are welcome.

Edit: algorithmic answers like the one by @stef are perfectly acceptable, but I am looking for a more mathematical form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a>1$ be an integer, and let $x$ and $y$ be positive integers such that $x^y=a$. If $a$ is *not* a perfect power then it follows that $x=a$ and $y=1$, and so the minimum value of $x+y$ is $a+1$.

If $a$ is a perfect power then we can[$^{1}$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190815/how-to-make-perfect-power-algorithm-more-efficient) write $a=b^c$ for integers $b$ and $c$ such that $b$ is not a perfect power. Then
$$x=b^d\qquad\text{ and }\qquad y=\frac cd,$$
for some divisor $d$ of $c$, and so we want to minimize $b^d+\tfrac cd$. Of course $b>1$ because $a>1$, and for
$$f(t):=b^t+\frac ct\qquad\text{ we have }\qquad f'(t)=b^t\ln b -\frac{c}{t^2},$$
and so $f'(t)=0$ if $f$ is minimal at $t$, because $f$ is continuous on the positive reals. Then $t^2b^t\ln b=c$, so
$$t^2e^{t\ln b}=\frac{\ln c}{\ln b}\qquad\text{ and so }\qquad we^w=\frac12\sqrt{(\ln b)(\ln c)},$$
where $w=\tfrac12t\ln b$. This shows that the minimum of $f$ over the positive reals is at
$$t_0=\frac{2}{\ln b}W\left(\frac12\sqrt{(\ln b)(\ln c)}\right).$$
Next note that $f$ is a convex function on the positive reals because
$$f''(t)=b^t(\ln t)^2+\frac{2c}{t^3},$$
which is strictly positive on the positive reals. It follows that the minimum of $f$ over the positive divisors of $c$ one of the two divisors nearest to the real minimum $t_0$. One can now simply check and compare these two divisors.

---

1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190815/how-to-make-perfect-power-algorithm-more-efficient

Comment: Great answer; given the relatively high number of named variables, may I suggest using different types of letters for $a$ and its divisors on the one hand, and for the powers of these divisors on the other hand? Maybe using latin letters for the divisors, and greek letters for the powers? Or starting the divisors at $a,b$ and the powers at $j,k$?

Comment: You took the minimum over all possible values of $t$, which was initially assumed to be a replacement for $d$, right? Now could you explain how you know that $t_0$ (either in its floor or ceil form) is a perfect divisor of $c$?

Comment: @SohamSaha You are absolutely right, good catch. I've corrected this last part.

Comment: Agreed on the correction. Also could you explain how you propose to choose $b$?

Comment: @SohamSaha It must be determined algorithmically, as suggested by the link. Effectively by checking whether $\sqrt[p]{a}$ is an integer for each prime $p\leq\tfrac{\ln a}{\ln 2}$.

Comment: Agreed. I believe then your method is dependent on the same algorithmic process as in the answer by @Stef, right? Since finally when comparing the closest divisor of $c$ to $t_0$, you'd have to do something like a search over the entire number space...

Comment: What if the question instead also gave the prime factorization of $a$? I think that then both problems can be resolved: choosing $b$ and choosing the $d$ closest to $t_0$...

Comment: @SohamSaha Similar but not the same. The other answer checks every $y$ up to $\log_2a$, this only checks primes up to $\log_2a$. For large $a$ this is significantly faster. It does add the cost finding the factors of $c$ nearest to $t_0$, but of course $c$ is 'small' compared to $a$.

Comment: @SohamSaha Indeed if you have the prime factorization of $a$ given as $a=\prod_{p\mid a}p^{a_p}$ then $c=\gcd_{p\mid a}(a_p)$ and $b=\prod_{p\mid a}p^{a_p/c}$, and we can compute $t_0$ explicitly. The divisors of $c$ nearest to $t_0$ can also be computed effectively.

Comment: I think you should include your last comment in your answer.

Comment: Found a discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2376860/1203597) regarding finding the divisor closest to a given number.

Answer (score 1):

A programmatic solution in python, iterating on the possible values of y between 1 and $\log_2(n)$:

```
from sympy.core.power import integer_nthroot

def clog2(n):
    """Ceiling of log2, https://stackoverflow.com/a/71122440/3080723 """
    if n <= 0:
        raise ValueError("domain error")
    return (n-1).bit_length()

def all_solutions(n):
    """All solutions (x, y) of x**y == n"""
    for y in range(1, clog2(n) + 1):
        x, is_exact = integer_nthroot(n, y)
        if is_exact:
            yield (x, y)

def smallest_sum_solution(n):
    """(x,y) that minimises x+y under constraint x**y == n"""
    return min(all_solutions(n), key=sum)
```

Testing:

````
for n in [2**6, 2**10, 6**40, 3**700]:
    x,y = smallest_sum_solution(n)
    print(f'{x}**{y} == {n}')

# 4**3 == 64
# 4**5 == 1024
# 6**40 == 13367494538843734067838845976576
# 81**175 == 9657802140591758043812442031522928437371194636776843099838260055342219733688083412928987321682880332396927287242805644548901834234972280564072880735127568242460394336247761481999342991210220561304479523441956128812808859393388776484808811910915541232693035534590226711458043242074211993816993921587180335757972232760635320184916654001
```
````

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not that much good in Python (is this Python even I am not sure, just guessing). Could you provide the associated pseudocode?

Comment: @SohamSaha There is a function `all_solutions` which does "For $y$ from 1 to $\log_2(n)$: $x \leftarrow \lfloor \sqrt[y]{n} \rfloor$; if $x^y = n$: keep $(x, y)$." and then there is `smallest_sum_solution` which calls `all_solutions` and returns the solution which minimises the sum `x+y`.

Comment: @SohamSaha And this is done using [function `integer_nthroot` from library sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.power.integer_nthroot) which simultaneously computes $\lfloor \sqrt[y]{n} \rfloor$ and tells us whether this integer solution is exact or not.

Comment: So , we are basically iterating over all possible base-exponent pairs and checking for the minimum, right?

Comment: And storing whether the given base-exponent pair is valid by using the is_exact boolean? Which is already a part of the output of the integer_nthroot function?

Comment: @SohamSaha Yes. We iterate through all the $(\lfloor \sqrt[y]{n} \rfloor, y)$ pairs and reject the ones for which `is_exact` is False.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help and for spending time on this question. Just a last question: What opinion do you have regarding this Sympy library? Is it suitable for other similar algorithmic number theory tasks? Or are there better alternatives too?

Comment: @SohamSaha Yes, it is suitable, and I don't know any better alternatives.